# Display an array with custom color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D numpy array called myArray made by integers ranging from 1 to 5.
I want to display this array using matplotlib, making sure that value 1 will be displayed as green, 2 as yellow, 3 as blue, 4 as black, 5 as red.

I wrote the following lines but colors don't correspond to values, because I don't know how to cope these.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
myColors = ["green", "yellow", "blue", "black", "red"]
myCmap = colors.ListedColormap(myColors)
plt.imshow(myArray, cmap = myCmap)
```

Comment: `plt.imshow(myArray, cmap=myCmap, vmin=1, vmax=5)` should work.

Comment: indeed it works. Thank you JohanC

Comment: vmin and vmax normally get calculated automatically from the data. You need to set them explicitly when 1 or 5 isn't present in your current array

Comment: But 1 and 5 are present in the array

Comment: If 1 and 5 are present, and no values lower than 1 or higher than 5, then your original approach would have worked. As a test, you could call `plt.colorbar()` to show which values correspond to which colors.